# How to use "fake" Clock with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

In the following example, I try to setup a fixed clock for the test:

```
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  return withClock(Clock.fixed(DateTime(2020, 1, 2, 3, 4)), () {
    test('test', () {
      expect(clock.now(), DateTime(2020, 1, 2, 3, 4));
    });
    
    testWidgets(
      'testWidgets',
      (tester) async {
        expect(clock.now(), DateTime(2020, 1, 2, 3, 4));
      },
    );
  });
}
```

However, it doesn't work and I get:

```
Expected: DateTime:<2020-01-02 03:04:00.000>
  Actual: DateTime:<2021-03-11 21:58:29.565006>

package:test_api                                   expect
expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:429
main.<fn>.<fn>
test/clock_test.dart:7

...

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: DateTime:<2020-01-02 03:04:00.000>
  Actual: DateTime:<2021-03-11 15:48:02.658728>

...

The test description was:
  clock
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

BTW: I tried to move `withClock` into the inner callback, but still reading `clock.now()` from widget's build methods doesn't yield the fixed clock.

Comment: From the pub, https://pub.dev/packages/fake_async perhaps?  I haven't used it myself but it might be what you need.

Comment: Fake_async is using Clock internally...